# Convert function in the sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please look the the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as total,
    DATEPART(hour,DateSent_dt) as hr,
    DATEPART(minute,DateSent_dt) as mm
FROM 
    dbname cd 
WHERE
    convert(varchar(10), cd.DateSent_dt, 111) >= convert(varchar(10), '#sdt#', 111)
    AND convert(varchar(10), cd.DateSent_dt, 111) <= convert(varchar(10), '#edt#', 111)
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(hour, DateSent_dt), DATEPART(minute, DateSent_dt)
ORDER BY 
    hr
```

What are `varchar(10)` and `111` doing in the `convert` function?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Could you explain in the context of my question?

Comment: it converts date to string of length 10, using "yyyy/mm/dd" format.

Comment: Thanks but why varchar(10) is used, it could be varchar(20) or different number inside the parenthesis ?

Comment: Because 111 =  yyyy/mm/dd = 10 characters ?

Comment: exactly, because result will be 10 chars long. But why strings are used for date comparasing is beyond me.

Comment: Check the Remarks section of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Convert function accepts three paramaters

- Target type
- Value/Column for conversion
- Style

For more information check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx